# How to update Protobuf Runtime Library?

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, keras, protocol-buffers

#### My Issue

I am struggeling with this error:

```
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:67]
This program requires version 3.4.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library,
but the installed version is 3.0.0.
Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself,
make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your
link-time library.
(Version verification failed in "external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/any.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
```

It is obviously telling me to update the 'Protobuf runtime library', but I have no clue how to accomplish that. Can anybody please help me on that?

I did not compile tensorflow myself, nor am I planning to do that.

#### My Context

I am in a python script, attempting to train a tensorflow model by the keras library; This line is causing the error:

```
keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=self.log_dir, histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=False)
```

Running on `Ubuntu 17.10 artful`

Here I share the output of some commands, that I used while trying to debug:

```
(venv) $ pip show protobuf                          
  Name: protobuf           
  Version: 3.6.1           
  Summary: Protocol Buffers
```

Also protoc is fine (but I need the 'runtime library', which is different from the 'compiler', I guess)

```
$ protoc --version                                   
  libprotoc 3.6.1
$ which protoc
  /usr/local/bin/protoc
```

#### My Attempts

The default package by `apt` is `libprotobuf10` (Version: 3.0.0).
So I installed a newer version from here https://launchpad.net/~maarten-fonville/+archive/ubuntu/protobuf without any changes in the error message

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/protobuf
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install libprotobuf15 # Version: 3.5.2
$ sudo apt install libprotobuf12 # Version: 3.4.1
```

I don't dare to `apt remove libprotobuf10`, because it will also remove `gnome-shell, ubuntu-desktop, ...` which sounds kinda dangerous.

Any ideas appreciated :)

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried to delete old `protoc` binary and replace it with new one?

Locate the location of your current `protoc` binary

```bash
which protoc
```

Delete old version of `protoc` binary:

```bash
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/protoc
```

Download latest or required version of `protoc`. For example [Protocol Buffers v3.9.1](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.9.1/protoc-3.9.1-linux-x86_64.zip)

Extract it somewhere you like.

Copy `protoc-3.9.1-linux-x86_64/bin/protoc` binary back to `/usr/local/bin`. That `protoc` file is the actual binary you want.

```bash
sudo mv /location/of/protoc-3.9.1-linux-x86_64/bin/protoc /usr/local/bin
```

After you moved `protoc` file to `/usr/local/bin` check its permissions as simple as `ls -la /usr/local/bin` and look for that `protoc` file. Probably you want to do `sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/protoc`.

It should be executable by default, but if in some strange case it is not, then probably you want to do `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/protoc`

Check protoc version now `protoc --version`

**UPDATE:**
Same applies to `/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/*` if you are using gRPC. If you are updating `protoc` compiler, then you should update those proto files as well. They change rarely, but... you never know.

Comment: Thanks. But since I'm not working on this project anymore, I cannot check correctness. I appreciate the effort anyway :)

Comment: This works in November 2022! Thanks.

Comment: http://google.github.io/proto-lens/installing-protoc.html